# SAS proc report order by without missing values

Tags: sas

```
proc report data=SORP_VOLUMES nofs;
  column SORP_START_DATE VOLUME VOLUME2;
  define VOLUME        / order order=internal noprint;
  define VOLUME2    / computed 'VOLUME';
      compute VOLUME2;
   VOLUME2 = VOLUME;
      endcomp; 
run;
```

I'm getting missing values for duplicate values in the volume column. E.g 2 . instead of 2 2 for each row.

Can anyone help?!?!

Comment: This has nothing to do with your problem or output, but NOWD is a much more common option to prevent the report from being interactive. I had to look up NOFS. Could just be my inexperience....

Answer (score 0):

Without your data, it is hard to understand what is happening.
However, the first thing to try is adding a define statement for SORP_START_DATE. Without that statement, SAS is making decisions about your output.